# Determine if type name is enum type

Tags: c#, types, enums, code-generation

I have a code generator that parses xml specifications of classes & properties - including the type of each property.

Properties of type `string` `int` `bool` are simple to process.

But if the type is not a primitive then I need to determine if it's a `class` or an `enum`

If I had an instance `MyObject` of `MyType` I could determine if `MyType` was an `enum type` via :

```
if (MyType.IsEnum()) {}
```

but all I have is the name of the type.

Comment: `Type.GetType("yourEnumType")` is this what you wnat?

Comment: this is odd : executed from the immediate window `Type.GetType("yourEnumType")` is null

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 instance.GetType().IsEnum
```

Or just

```
myType.IsEnum;
```

UPD. Does not noticed that you have only type name.

```
Type.GetType("my_type").IsEnum
```

Comment: OP said he have only name of type, not Type or instance of type

Answer (score 1):

try [Type.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) think it does what your looking for, or at least will return a Type object then you can call .IsEnum

you'll need to use the fully qualified name for your type, like "MyNamespace.MyType" not just "MyType"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Type.GetType("nameofEnum")` method

From MSDN [Type.GetType Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the Type with the specified name, performing a case-sensitive
>   search

To get it work you need provide assembly qualified name of enum type

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace

```
Type enumType = Type.GetType("AssemblyName.EnumName");
bool isEnum = enumType.IsEnum;
```

So if your enum declared inside some namespace you need include full "path"

```
namespace Project
{
    namespace MyAllEnums
    {
        public enum DesignPatterns
        {
            Spagetti = 0,
            Factory = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Then for getting type use

```
Type enumType = Type.GetType("Project.MyAllEnums.DesignPatterns");
if (enumType.IsEnum)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you haven't information about assembly name of enum type, then another approach will be check all assemblies you have and return first type with name you trying to find.

Example for current assembly

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type enumType = assembly.GetType("yourEnumType");
```

In the way above you get type without assembly qualified name, but be aware if your enum declared inside inner namespace it will not work.